# What does private MyShovel Shovel mean?

Tags: java, syntax, nomenclature

I am having great difficulties understanding this construct

```
 public class MyBucket extends bucket {
   private double var1;
   private MyShovel Shovel; <- this is the problem here

   public MyBucket(int volume, MyShovel Shovel) {

      Some code here

   }
  }
```

I cannot understand what  private MyShovel Shovel is in Java terminology. It is a class defined in my project but I cannot determine what it is called in the Java world. Can someone please help me define it so I can research what it is. This is production code and it works. Just cannot figure out the official Java name for that construct.

Comment: `Shovel` is a *private*, *instance level* field of type `MyShovel` in `MyBucket` class. Note : `Shovel` is just a *reference* to an instance of `MyShovel`

Comment: `shovel` is an instance variable, member or field of `MyBucket`

Comment: *member variable* or *field* By Java naming conventions, it should be `shovel`, not `Shovel`. Variables should start with a lowercase letter; types start with uppercase.

Comment: Hmm, just change it to `MyShovel shovel`, and you will get it!

Answer (score 1):

`Shovel` is a (private) member. Its type is `MyShovel`. This means that every instance of `MyBucket` contains a reference to a `MyShovel` object, which can be referenced only from within the class, by the name `Shovel`.

Note that this declaration does **not** follow java naming conventions. In the proper conventions it would have been called `myShovel`, in lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Even better :) just wanted to highlight the conversation there.

Answer (score 1):

`Shovel` is just a variable. It is an instance of `MyShovel`. `MyShovel` would be a `Class` that represents a virtual shovel. Since it is a global variable, or `field`, in `MyBucket` this means that each `MyBucket` also would have `MyShovel` inside of it.

In the code you provided it is undefined and has no value. Since it is `private` only methods in `MyBucket` can access it. The `MyBucket` constructor takes a `MyShovel` parameter and is most likely what `Shovel` is set to.

**You can think of it like this:** 
Every `MyBucket` must have a `MyShovel` inside of it to make it work. So when creating a `MyBucket` you put a `MyShovel` inside of it. `Shovel` is the space that that particular `MyShovel` will be stored.

As others mentioned it should be named "shovel" for naming convention.